# How to disable deep linker in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Is it possible to disable deep linker in Ionic application.
For example, if I call `this.navCtrl.push('SomePage');` then URL is changed to `http://localhost/some-page`
I need URL NOT to be changed. Is it possible?

Comment: You could try to use modals. As far as I know, modals do not change the url. But they behave like pushed pages.